# accelerometer not working in htc one x

Tags: accelerometer

I created a simple application to work with accelerometer, what it does is, when the phone is tilted ie, in x axis a sound is played.. i hd done the program successfully and also deployed it in my mobile (no error) but the program is working but while tilting sound is not played, ie accelerometer is not working..i thought my phone has sm problm bt its sensor is working when perfectly while playing games, browser and all...what is the problem? pls wil anyone say what is d problm? is it my phone's problem? im attaching the code also..

```
package com.antony.am;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    float x,y,sensorX,sensorY;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    int i=0;
    SensorManager sm;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MyEventListener el;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        el=new MyEventListener();
        x=y=sensorX=sensorY=0;
        // tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        sm=(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!=0){
            Sensor s=sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
            sm.registerListener(el, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
        //e.values[0]=x direction change
        //e.values[1]=y direction change
        //e.values[2]=z direction change

        if((int)e.values[0]==6){
            mp.start();
        }
        else if((int)e.values[0]==-6){
            mp.start();
        }

        //tv1.setTextSize(e.values[0]*10);
        //tv2.setTextSize(e.values[0]*10);
        //tv1.setText(Integer.toString((int) e.values[0]));
        //tv2.setText(Integer.toString((int) e.values[1]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sm.unregisterListener(el);
        super.onPause();
        mp.stop();
    }

    class MyEventListener implements SensorEventListener{

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        }
    }
}
```